# Store values in loop into vector with seq

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector

I can store values in a loop to a vector effectively when writing a loop likeso:

```
z = 0.5
x <- vector("numeric", 10)
for(i in 1:10){
x[i] <- z - i/10 
}
>[1]  0.4  0.3  0.2  0.1  0.0 -0.1 -0.2 -0.3 -0.4 -0.5
```

However, when I use a sequence of numbers instead of a colon separator likeso:

```
z = 0.5
x <- vector("numeric", 20)
for(i in seq(0.05, 1, 0.05)){
x[i] <- z - i
}
>[1] -0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

It fails to return me a vector for each  iteration of `i`, why does it do this and how can I get the loop to work effectively with `seq()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index also becomes a double, that's the issue. You may define a vector `I` with the numbers and loop over the `seq`uence of indices. Subset both the `I` and the result `x` with `i`.

```
z <- 0.5
x <- vector("numeric", 20)
I <- seq(0.05, 1, 0.05)
for (i in seq(I)) {
  x[i] <- z - I[i]
}
x
# [1]  0.45  0.40  0.35  0.30  0.25  0.20  0.15  0.10  0.05
# [10]  0.00 -0.05 -0.10 -0.15 -0.20 -0.25 -0.30 -0.35 -0.40
# [19] -0.45 -0.50
```

Just in case that was not just a simplified example of something, since R is vectorized you may also do just

```
z - seq(0.05, 1, 0.05)
# [1]  0.45  0.40  0.35  0.30  0.25  0.20  0.15  0.10  0.05
# [10]  0.00 -0.05 -0.10 -0.15 -0.20 -0.25 -0.30 -0.35 -0.40
# [19] -0.45 -0.50
```